# How to render programmatically created table in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**ERROR:**

main.js:1583 Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object HTMLTableElement]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead or wrap the object using createFragment(object) from the React add-ons.

---

**CODE:**

```
var size = 40

var Board = createReactClass ({

    getInitialState() {
        var array = [];
        var cellsArray = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < size; i ++) {
            array.push(cellsArray);
            for (var j = 0; j > size; j++) {
                array[i].push(<Cell start={this.props.start}/>);
            }
        }

        return {
            array: array
        };

    },

    render() {

    var i = 0;

    var tableData = this.state.array.map(rowData => {
        i++
        return (
            <tr key={i}>
                {
                    rowData.map(cellData => {
                        return ({cellData});
                    })
                }
            </tr>
        );
    })

    return (
        <table>
            <tbody>
                {tableData}
            </tbody>
        </table>
    );

}

})

var Cell = createReactClass ({

    getInitialState() {
        return {
            selected : false,
        }
    },

    handleClick() {
        this.setState({
            selected: !this.state.selected
        })
    },

    render() {
        return <td onClick = {this.handleClick} className={this.state.selected ? "cell selected" : "cell"}></td>;
    }
})
```

---

**QUESTION:**

I would like to render the programmatically created table. How can I do that ?

---

**UPDATE:**

[image]

[image]

---

**CSS:**

```
.cell {
    width: 1em;
    height: 1em;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.selected {
    background-color: black;
}

table {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    margin: auto;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}
```

Comment: `document.createElement('table')` is a bad idea, just return `<table>{tableData.map(rowData => <tr>...` and so on

Comment: @elmeister  Could you please put this in an answer so I can accept it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create it `React` way. Your `createTable` method should look something like below.

```
createTable(tableData) {
 return (
  <table>
   <tbody>
   {
    tableData.map(rowData => {
      return (<tr key={rowData.Id}>
          {
           rowData.map(cellData => {
              return (<td key={cellData}> {cellData} </td>);
           })
          }
        </tr>);
    })
   }
  </tbody>
  </table>
 )
```

Note: You need to put in a unique key for the root of jsx inside the 'maps'. Identify the unique key for each iteration. As a last resort you can use `index`, but that is not recommended.

**EDIT: Updated for new changes**

In your updated code, the `td` is empty and hence its displayed empty on the page.

Other changes you would require

Your initial state should not generate an JSX. It should be used only to compute the initial state and return a plain object. You are returning a object that contains array of JSX elements in it, which fundamentally defeats the purpose of React that it needs to require the DOM to be dynamically updated appropriately based on `prop`/`state` changes. Your `initialState` should only contain the data that is required to construct the needed DOM elements.

```
getInitialState() {
    var array = [];
    var cellsArray = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < size; i ++) {
        array.push(cellsArray);
        for (var j = 0; j > size; j++) {
            array[i].push(/* push data that you need to construct your cell */);
        }
    }

    return {
        array: array
    };

}
```

Then in your `tableData` function , you need to form the required JSX. This function is getting called inside of `render` which is perfectly fine place to produce the DOM elements.

```
var tableData = this.state.array.map(rowData => {
    i++
    return (
        <tr key={i}>
            {
                rowData.map(cellData => {
                    return <Cell key={cellData} data={cellData} start={this.props.start} />
                })
            }
        </tr>
    );
})
```

Finally in your `Cell`, `render` method you need to pass some children for `td` for it to be visible on the screen. In you question its empty and so the image you have posted showing the DOM elements and it being empty is the right behaviour. You need to do something like below

```
render() {
    return (<td onClick = {this.handleClick} className={this.state.selected ? "cell selected" : "cell"}>
 {this.props.data }
 { /*  or whatever data you want to be put here */ }
  </td>);
 }
```

Comment: Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop. Check the top-level render call using <tbody>.

Comment: well. That is pretty much updated now. Always you need to make modifications to the code to suit your needs.

Comment: Its bad idea to create the JSX components in other places that inside `render`'s context. You have to move it inside the `<td>` by putting the logic inside it.  State should only hold `plain` javascript objects.

Comment: 1) Change `var j = 0; j > size; j++` to `var j = 0; j < size; j++`, 2) Change `return ({cellData});` to `return (cellData);`